# Bootstrap modal disappears too quickly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've tried everything I could find, but to no avail. I'm able to get the bootstrap modals to animate in however I like, but adjusting the "out" animation is not working for me. The modal starts to animate and then just vanishes in less than a second.

How do I change the behaviour of the modal dialogue so it can be animated as I choose?

Here's some example code that I've used:

```css
/*Credit: http://hawkee.com/snippet/16154/ - modified by me*/
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 top: 300px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 1.5s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 0);
 opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.35s;
}
```

It works just fine - except the "disappearing act".

Comment: can u share your complete code...!

Comment: This _is_ the complete code - it's the only thing that's any different from the default that needs to be posted, anything else would waste people's time.